# How to make a div that has background image clickable to another page in bootstrap

Tags: html, css

I want to make this image clickable to another Page. I've set image to div by css as code below.

```css
.image1 {
  background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1486611367184-17759508999c?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=666&q=80);
}
```

```html
<div class="row">

  <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4">

    <div class="img-thumbnail">

      <div class="image image1">
        <a href="#" class="badge badge-dark">Electronics</a>
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a try of this

Wrap the div in the anchor - this is allowed in newer HTML (alternatively make the anchor a block element and put the image as background on the anchor - see [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63463047/295783) by F Müller):

```css
.image1 {
  background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1486611367184-17759508999c?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=666&q=80);
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4">
    <div class="img-thumbnail">
      <a href="https://google.com/search" class="badge badge-dark">
        <div class="image image1">
          Electronics
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

OR extend the click to the div using JavaScript if you have no other way

```js
window.addEventListener("load",function() { // on page load
  document.addEventListener("click",function(e) { // change document to the closest static container
    let tgt = e.target; // what was clicked
    let badge = tgt.querySelector(".badge"); // anchor could be inside
    if (tgt.classList.contains("image") && tgt.contains(badge) || tgt.classList.contains(".badge")) { // or it could be the anchor
      location = badge.href+"?q="+badge.textContent; // use the anchor href
    }
  })
})
```

```css
.image1 {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1486611367184-17759508999c?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=666&q=80);
}

.image1 a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4">
    <div class="img-thumbnail">
      <div class="image image1">
        <a href="https://google.com/search" class="badge badge-dark">Electronics</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: There is no need for an on click event in javascript when you have an `<a>` tag. besides `<a>` also sets `cursor: pointer` by default.

Comment: @F.Müller OP wants the complete DIV that has the link in it to be clickable. So yes, we DO need to intercept clicks on the div OR wrap the div in the anchor - see updated answer

Comment: I can live with the updated example. However, it makes no sense to have a markup like that at all. It is counter-logical and all you need is already provided by plain html. Using javascript in this case is quite a sin IMO.

Comment: @F.Müller We have no real knowledge of what else OP is doing with this. It is possible that the markup cannot be changed at all (wordpress plugin) so now OP had 3 different solutions

Comment: I agree. Nonetheless, it makes sense to point it out at least. Doing it the right way is always better than building a workaround for a x-y problem. If he cannot change the markup however then sure. But that was not part of the question in the first place - neither was a CMS. Alright, I will upvote this solution if you get rid of that javascript part or at least refer to it as "you should only do that if needed".

Answer (score 3):

All you need is an anchor tag `<a>` and you set the `background-image` on that tag. In this way you can also get rid of some of the markup (redundant).

You can use `display: block` to make the `<a>` behave like a `<div>`. In this case it will cover 100% of the available width and height of the parent element.

```css
.image {
  display: block;
  height: 200px;
  background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1486611367184-17759508999c?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=666&q=80);
  color: wheat;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: left center;
}

.thumbnail {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
Like this:
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4">
    <div class="img-thumbnail">
      <a href="https://www.example.com" class="image">Electronics</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

or even:

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4">
    <a href="https://www.example.com" class="image thumbnail">Electronics</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You should emphasise the important part where you make the anchor a block element

Comment: yeah! its better! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can add the URL to href element in a tag. you can set

```css
.image1 {
  background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1486611367184-17759508999c?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=666&q=80);
}
.image1 a {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">

  <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4">

    <div class="img-thumbnail">

      <div class="image image1">
        <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/" class="badge badge-dark">Electronics</a>
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>
```

there can be many ways to achieve this depends on your need.as an example in case you plan to add more elements inside the div you can use javascript to achieve this.

You can add the onclick for JavaScript into the div.

```css
#box {
    cursor: pointer;
    background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1486611367184-17759508999c?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=666&q=80);
    height:300px;
    width:100%;
    color:white;
    font-size:32px;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px #000;
}
```

```html
<div onclick="location.href='https://stackoverflow.com/';" id="box">
The content of the div here
</div>
```

Comment: There is no need for javascript when you have anchor tag.

Comment: yeah, I just added it as a reference in case he plans to add many contents inside it, etc.i updated the answer thank for pointing it out.